# React - High CPU usage on website idle even when no events happening

Tags: html, reactjs, performance, cpu

I have a react app, its fairly complicated but nothing crazy.

Noticed quite high CPU usage, doing some investigation seems like its constantly using on 50% cpu on the chrome task manager.

Looking into the performance tabs, there are no events happening. Yet this constant CPU usage. Also noticed something called a "task" happening pretty often but offers no information about what it is.

Anyone got any suggestions of things i can try or look at ?

Thanks

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSWgY.png]

[image]

Comment: Try closing the developer tools and other tabs and see if the CPU calms down. The tools you're using, use computational power, too. Your performance tab looks good. The compositor might be firing each 'animation' frame, but it only appears to run for 5 out of the 15+ shown milliseconds here, which shouldn't add up to 50% on its own. It might also be computing mouse hover state or something, I'm not sure about what it exactly does.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Thanks for the reply, iv just noticed if i delete my css file this totally stops, going to keep investigating if i have wrote terrible CSS

Comment: If you're heavily using (continuous) animations, maybe see if you can reduce the complexity of those (either in HTML or CSS might help).

Comment: @JochemKuijpers 

The page is as idle as can be during the testing. 

Iv disabled these 2 rules and its no longer doing this :

  // -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  // backface-visibility: hidden;

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is curious. If the property is statically assigned to whichever element you're dealing with, that might be a performance bug. In which case, reporting it to the Chome devs might be your best bet in getting it solved (as well as helping the software get better). Can you check other browsers as well if this behavior is mimicked?

Comment: Do a profiling with react dev tools for chrome. You will get more info whats happening...

Comment: Hare you compiled that in production mode?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers i should note that css was on a * selector, removing it totally reduced the CPU constant load, i also checked page paints (none), nothing at all was happening, i may try and replicate it on a slim example and submit it, thanks